# Mongodb Get subdocument and filter by date

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with following documents.

```
{
    "id":1,
    "url":"mysite.com",
    "views":
     [
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-03-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"2.2.2.2","date":ISODate("2015-03-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.0Z")}
     ]
},
{
    "id":2,
    "url":"mysite2.com",
    "views":
     [
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-01-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"2.2.2.2","date":ISODate("2015-01-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.0Z")},
       {"ip":"1.1.1.1","date":ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.0Z")}
     ]
}
```

How can I get documents where `id = 1` and `date(Y-m) = 2015-02` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation pipeline operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). The following will return all subdocuments in the `views` array that match your criteria.

[**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) to filter select document with given `id`
[**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the views array. In your first [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage use the [**`$year`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year) operator to return the year for date and [**`$month`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month) the month for the date. Next filter your documents by `month` and `year` using `$match`. [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your document by `_id` and use another `$project` stage to reshape them.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {'$match': {'id': 1}}, 
        {'$unwind': '$views'}, 
        {'$project': {
            'id': 1,
            'year': {'$year': '$views.date'}, 
            'month': {'$month': '$views.date'}, 
            'url': 1, 'views': 1
            }
        }, 
        {'$match': {'year': 2015, 'month': 2}},
        {'$group': {
                       '_id': '$id', 
                       'url': {'$first': 'url'}, 
                       'views': {'$push': '$views'}
                   }
        },
        {'$project': {'id': '$_id', 'views': 1, 'url': 1, '_id': 0}}
    ]
)
```

**Result**

```js
{
    "url" : "url",
    "views" : [
            {
                    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40Z")
            },
            {
                    "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40Z")
            }
    ],
    "id" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the specific `"views"` array element (subdocument) that satisfies the above criteria, use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator as follows:

```
var start = new Date(2015, 0, 31, 23, 59, 59),
    end = new Date(2015, 2, 1);
db.test.find(
{
    id: 1, 
    "views.date": { "$gt": start, "$lt": end}
}, 
{
    "id": 1,
    "views": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "date": { "$gt": start, "$lt": end} 
        } 
    }
});
```

Returns:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("555089bf9cd8fa39c7971e33"),
    "id" : 1,
    "views" : [ 
        {
            "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to return just the whole document then use the date range query without the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection as follows:

```
var start = new Date(2015, 0, 31, 23, 59, 59),
    end = new Date(2015, 2, 1);
db.test.find({id: 1, "views.date": { "$gt": start, "$lt": end}})
```

The query above will return the whole document which matched the above criteria, including as=ll the subdocuments:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5550866d9cd8fa39c7971e2e"),
    "id" : 1,
    "url" : "mysite.com",
    "views" : [ 
        {
            "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-13T13:34:40.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "ip" : "2.2.2.2",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-03-13T13:34:40.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.000Z")
        }, 
        {
            "ip" : "1.1.1.1",
            "date" : ISODate("2015-02-13T13:34:40.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```